# Creating an empty txt file on Mac OS without opening an application first

Tags: macos, textmate, shortcut

Is there a way to simply create a new document e.g. on the Desktop and open it with e.g. textmate with a simple shortcut or script. I know that the MS Windows approach where you can just create a new empty txt file directly is not working for Mac. 
I am looking for a method achieving something similar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[alt text http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/2280/screenshot20100106at125.png](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/2280/screenshot20100106at125.png)

This uses TextMate's `mate` command line helper application.

If it's not installed, go to TextMate > Help > Terminal Usage.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
ntf="Untitled $(date +%s).txt"
touch "$ntf"
mate "$ntf"
```

- Save this on your Desktop as "New Text File.command"
- Make it executable (in Terminal: chmod +x "New Text File.command")
- Optional: Copy and paste the TextMate icon from TextMate.app's "Get Info" dialog in to your new file's "Get Info" dialog.

Comment: Ah.. I think you can make Terminal close windows automatically, but you tell it to quit (and probably close just one window, too), with a final line of AppleScript: osascript -e 'Tell application "Terminal" to quit'

Answer (score 48):

You can write this in the terminal:

```
touch filename.txt
```

Or as a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch filename.txt
```

Comment: but then I need a filename first … or using some timestamp, hm …

Answer (score 8):

How about the unix approach of creating an empty file with `touch` ?

It could be done in a script, and passed to an application.

Answer (score 2):

Traditional on the shell is to use the `touch` command. But in any programming language you can do it without running an external program by opening a file with the O_CREAT flag:

in **C**:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

close(open("myfile.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664));
```

in **Perl**:

```
open TEMP '>', 'myfile.txt';
close TEMP;
```

in **Tcl**:

```
close [open "myfile.txt" w+]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another to create new files, you can also create your own templates with it. Just search for NewDoc in AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few third party tools that add that kind of functionality. The newest I've seen is [Templates](http://curmi.com/Templates.html)